# su in shell script started from ssh works in other terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, sudo

Sorry my dumb question but I don't know how to describe my situation.

There are logs from Jenkins:

```
ssh www.myserver.com '/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/deploy_webapp.sh'
+ id
uid=1004(jenkins) gid=1004(jenkins) groups=1004(jenkins),107(tomcat7)
+ sudo su tomcat7
+ id
uid=1004(jenkins) gid=1004(jenkins) groups=1004(jenkins),107(tomcat7)
```

Due to security reasons I can't access to myserver with tomcat7 user. "sudo su tomcat7" works without password because I've added this only command to /etc/sudoers with NOPASSWD.

So, the question is:
Why I can't **su** to my **tomcat7** user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the script `deploy_webapp.sh` contains this sequence of commands:

```
id
sudo su tomcat7
id
```

### What happens there?

1. `ssh` starts the script `deploy_webapp.sh` in a process owned by user `jenkins`.
2. `sudo` is started as a new process and changes the process owner to `root`.
3. `sudo` starts `su` as `root` in another process.
4. `su` tries to start login shell of the user `tomcat7` as user `tomcat7`.
5. `tomcat7` most probably does not have an interactive shell configured (check `grep tomcat7 /etc/passwd`).
6. `su` exits. (In this session there is no process owned by `tomcat7` any more.)
7. `sudo` exits. (In this session there is no process owned by `root` any more.)
8. Last `id` is executed under the same user as the whole script `deploy_webapp.sh` - `jenkins`. The whole script is being executed under the same user. Neither `sudo` nor `su` changes that.

### What you can do?

1. Call `su` with the shell you need. For example: `su -s /bin/bash`
2. Run the second `id` in a process owned by `tomcat7`. For example: `su tomcat7 -c id`

Complete example script:

```
id
sudo su tomcat7 -s /bin/bash -c id
```

### Summary

All the commands to be executed under `tomcat7` should be run in a process started by `su` (by option `-c`) and pay attention to login shells of users.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've fixed my script:
`ssh www.myserver.com sudo su tomcat7 -s /bin/bash -c /var/<>/deploy_webapp.sh`
(/etc/sudoers entry was fixed too)